# How to find components in listbox item, in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I need to retrieve components from a listbox item. Not from a Tap or selection changed events. Is there a simple way to achieve this?
If I remember correct, in Android you can just write:

```
layoutRoot.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Is there a similar way to do this on Windows Phone?

---

Update: Here's what I tried so far, but does not work:

What Daniela said in option 5 seems to work when I have the ListBoxItem. So this works fine when I have for example a Tap event on the ListBoxItem:

```
private void ListBoxItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = sender as ListBoxItem;
    // I can now retrieve a component inside the ListBoxItem
    TextBox textBox = item.FindName("myTextBox") as TextBox;
}
```

But I want to do this when not triggering any events from a ListBoxItem.
What JoonasL said looks like something I could use but I can't get it to work.

```
// will not compile ( Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to... )
ListBoxItem item = x.Items[0];

// if cast the value will be null
ListBoxItem item = x.Items[0] as ListBoxItem;

// will return the object used to populate that ListBoxItem, not the actual ListBoxItem.
// item will have a ItemViewModel object.
List<ItemViewModel> list = ....
this.myListBox.ItemsSource = list;
var item = x.Items[0]
```

When searching on Google I found something that I could use to find a component inside a ListBoxItem but I think there should be a easier way. Here they use a [VisualTreeHelper](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7).

Comment: Would you please mark the correct answer so others can also get some help?

Comment: @IrisClasson
I can't mark any answer as correct when it has not solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

Edit:
add a name to your lisbox (x:Name="something")
Cast ALL items as a List or pick out an item and cast the item as the correct type. Example:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var list = yourListbox.Items;
  var itemCastAsCorrectObjectInstance = (ItemViewModel)list.FirstOrDefault();
  textblock.Text = itemCastAsCorrectObjectInstance.LineOne;
}
```

ItemViewModel is a class we have created, and a list of ItemViewModels are used as itemssource for the listbox.

[Here is an app example I've made for you](http://www.irisclasson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/WP7App1.zip)

There are several ways to do that (some of the examples are WPF, but code is quite similar, it's just to give you a general idea)

1. Create listbox in code and retrieve item as in the example provided my JoonasL

   ```
       private void GetUserRecommendations()
   {
       var obj = _helper.GetList<Recommendations>(@"http://localhost:1613/Home/GetAllRecommendations");

       _items.Clear();

       foreach (var item in obj)
       {
           _items.Add(item);
       }

       itemListView.ItemsSource = _items;
   }
   ```
2. Retrieve a selected item on a changed event (or other event bound to the listbox)

   ```
       void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
   {
       var itemProperty = ((ListBoxItem) e.ClickedItem).SomeProperty;
   }
   ```
3. Provide the listbox a name and access the items by refering to the name in the code

   var item = itemListView.SelectedItem as SomeClass;
4. Access the selected item by binding to another element (XAML only)

   ```
   <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3" Padding="8">
   <DockPanel>
     <TextBlock>Choose a Color:</TextBlock>
     <ComboBox Name="myComboBox" SelectedIndex="0">
       <ComboBoxItem>Green</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem>Blue</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem>Red</ComboBoxItem>
     </ComboBox>
     <Canvas>
       <Canvas.Background>
         <Binding ElementName="myComboBox" Path="SelectedItem.Content"/>
       </Canvas.Background>
     </Canvas>
   </DockPanel>
   ```
5. Search the layoutroot

var myTextBlock = (TextBlock)this.FindName("myTextBlock");

Or maybe something like:

```
    private void Somepage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SomeCondition())
    {
        var children = (sender as Panel).Children;
        var child = (from Control child in children
                 where child.Name == "NameTextBox"
                 select child).First();
        child.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: Option 5 actually works if I have a reference to a ListBoxItem, e.g:  
  
`listBoxItem.FindName("myTextBlock");`  

But how do I access a ListBoxItem when not triggering any events from the ListBox. This works:  
  
`private void ListBoxItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = sender as ListBoxItem;
    var textBox = item.FindName("myTextBox");
}`  
  

What @JoonasL said does not work:  
  
`ListBox x = new ListBox();
ListBoxItem item = x.Items[0];`  
  
x.Items[0] returns the object used to populate the ListBox and not the acutal ListBoxItem

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBox x = new ListBox();
ListBoxItem item = x.Items[0];
```

Or do you want something else?

Comment: `x.Items[0]`will only return the object used to populate that ListBoxItem not the actual ListBoxItem

Comment: iixi JoonasL is right- the example shows how to get first item- and its components. If you want what is populating the listboxitem then you have to cast the item to the correct type. C# is a strongly-typed language, we like types ;)

Answer (score 0):

RadDataBoundListBox has an event called ItemTap (not sure about normal ListBox) but my solution went something like this:

```
private void FocusTextBox(object sender, ListBoxItemTapEventArgs e)
{           
                txtBox = e.Item.FindChildByType<TextBox>();

                var item = itemListView.SelectedItem as PanoramaApp1.//Your Selected Item Type Here;

                //Do Something With item Here

                itemListView.SelectedItem = null;
}
```